# How to join tables to get only the last record of has-many association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have two models: Company and Transaction (has-many relationship). Transaction model has `balance` attribute. I have a query to join the models:

```
scope :joined_transactions, (lambda do
  select('transactions.balance as current_balance')
  .joins('LEFT OUTER JOIN transactions ON transactions.company_id = companies.id')
end)
```

However, I want to include only the last transaction into this query. As a result `Company.joined_transactions.first.current_balance == Company.first.transactions.last.balance` should be true.

Comment: The only place it's clear that you're talking about Ruby on Rails and ActiveRecord is in your tags.

Comment: That's what tags are for

Answer (score 6):

subquery `.joins('left join transactions t on t.company_id = companies.id AND t.id = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM transactions WHERE transactions.company_id = t.company_id)')`

Answer (score -3):

I believe this problem was already solved many times. You can do it using [subquery](https://stackoverflow.com/a/725164/1980034) or [double join](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2111420/1980034).

Please add more info on your current case if this doesn't work for you

Comment: I realize that his intent wasn't clear except in his tags, but neither of those are ActiveRecord solutions.

Comment: Rarely do you find a problem in computer science that hasn't been solved many times.